# JavaScript using bool to control callbacks

Tags: javascript

I have a bool variable that I have initially declared true.

I have an `.on('click')`event that checks if the bool is true and if so, if calls `function1`, and `function1` sets the bool to false.

If bool is false `function2` is called and sets bool to true.

However, the bool is not working as it should and I am a lost for why.

My code is below:

```
cells.on('click', function(d, i) {
      if (d.vis === 'text') {
        console.log('test');
        if (this.boolGame == true) {
          myThis.updateList(d);
          console.log('setting false');

        } else if (this.boolGame == false) {
          myThis.collapseList();
          console.log('true');

        }
```

This is a sample of one of the functions

```
 collapseList() {

    let gameList = this.tableElements.filter(d => d.value.type == 'games');
    console.log(gameList);
    // this.tableElements.splice();
    console.log('false');
    this.boolGame = false;

}
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196). I see that you  have a `myThis` variable that you use to call the functions, but you are using `this.boolGame` to compare the value. You probably want to use `myThis.boolGame` instead. Also, you never want to use loose comparison to compare against booleans. In your case you should just use `if (myThis.boolGame) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: chances are `this` is not what you expect inside an event handler

Comment: What's is the `this` object? When you have an event click, the callback function will have `this` set to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `console.log(this.boolGame)`. It's not working because it's `undefined`. functions that are created with the `function` syntax have their own context. As in, it has created its own `this` variable and it doesn't contain any attributes that you set in the scope above it. You have two options: using `bind`, or an arrow function.

1. `bind`. Turn it into a named function and use `bind` on it. This creates a copy of `this.cellsHandler` with the inner context you're looking for.

   ```
   this.cellsHandler = function(d, i) {
     if (d.vis === 'text') {
       console.log('test');
       if (this.boolGame == true) {
         myThis.updateList(d);
         console.log('setting false');
       } else if (this.boolGame == false) {
         myThis.collapseList();
         console.log('true');
       }
     }
   }
   cells.on('click', this.cellsHandler.bind(this))
   ```
2. Turn your function into an arrow function. Arrow functions have no context, so it takes in the `this` from the scope above it, which has `boolGame` in it. I recommend this approach.

   ```
   cells.on('click', (d, i) => {
     if (d.vis === 'text') {
       console.log('test');
       if (this.boolGame == true) {
         myThis.updateList(d);
         console.log('setting false');
       } else if (this.boolGame == false) {
         myThis.collapseList();
         console.log('true');
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the help! I get messed up with the change of 'this'. I implemented the second example but for some reason it doesn't recognize the bool initialized as true and neither of the functions are executed. The .on event is in an update function and I have the "let boolGame = true;" within an above constructor function. Within the update function when I console.log(this.boolGame); it comes back as undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: @jrogers12 Wait, are you saying you have `let boolGame = true` in your constructor? Do you actually mean you have `this.boolGame = true`? Because the two are very different.

Comment: I have let boolGame = true within the constructor. I did not want to declare the this.booGame = true outside of the .on click event but within the update function because it gets called more to redraw the table.

Comment: @jrogers12 Just to make sure we're on the same page: assigning a variable with `let var const` make them local variables. They are only available inside your constructor `function`. You cannot access `let boolGame` anywhere else. I am confused by your intended usage of `this.boolGame` now. What do you mean when you say that `this.boolGame` gets called multiple times? Isn't that the point?

Comment: ah, haha that is my problem then. Thank you!